# append an existing line | centos

Tags: bash, centos, vi

I would like to append an existing line in a file (Cent OS).
For example I have a file that have the following

```
# I will like to add hash 
to this line
```

so adding hash to the 'to this line'

Using sed will do the trick?

**

- Update:

** just so you for general information, I'm using this to edit sudoers file this will be part of a script I'm working on.

Comment: Try: `sed "s/\(to this line\)/\1 hash/g;" test.txt`. If it looks ok:  
use `sed -i "s/\(to this line\)/\1 hash/g;" test.txt`. Where test.txt is your file.

Comment: close, but I need to add # to the beginning of the line, do you know which flag need to be use to add it to the beginning of the file?

Comment: use `sed "s/\(to this line\)/# \1/g;" test.txt`, `\1` refers to the expression in parentheses, so the replacement in the second part of the sed s command puts the `#` in front of the `to this line`. Do you want to comment out a line containing `to this line` somewhere in it?

Comment: `sed -i.bak '/to this line/s/^/# /' test.txt`

Comment: @LarsFischer Thank you, yes I need to comment out a line in visudo looks like your second working but not on a statement with a lot of space    sudo sed "s/\(Defaults    requiretty\)/# \1/g;" /etc/sudoers

Comment: I think Joao answer is perfect, 1. it restricst the s command to lines matching `to this line`. 2. it inserts the hash in front of the line.

Comment: Actually, It's working just recheck. Thank you very much guys!